# recursion for n-dimensional matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am doing some implementation in Python 3 and I need some help. I have function, that is dependent on the dimension of matrixes. I actually have two matrixes and want to get third one in some way. For example (2-dimensional matrixes):

```py
def my_matrix_2d(mat1, mat2):
    ar = []
    for i in range(len(mat1[0])):
        ar1 = []
        for j in range(len(mat1[1])):
            try:
                ar1.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat2[i][j]])
            except IndexError:
                ar1.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], None])
        ar.append(ar1)
    return ar
```

Another example for 3-dimensional matrixes:

```py
def my_matrix_3d(mat1, mat2):
    ar = []
    for i in range(len(mat1[0])):
        ar1 = []
        for j in range(len(mat1[1])):
            ar2 = []
            for k in range(len(mat1[2])):
                try:
                    ar2.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], mat2[i][j][k]])
                except IndexError:
                    ar2.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], None])
            ar1.append(ar2)
        ar.append(ar1)
    return ar
```

I need to do a general function for n-dimensional matrixes. I know it has to be something with the recursion, but I just can't figure it out. 
I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I actually didn't describe my problem very well, so I will try to give detailed description. Firstly, i will describe 2D problem. I have two matrixes, mat1 and mat2. len(mat1)=2, and let's say that len(mat1[0])=m and len(mat1[1])=n. Then, mat2 is m x n matrix, so len(mat2)=m and len(mat2[i])=n for i=0,1,...,m-1. my_matrix_2d is function, that combine this two matrixes in some way. Let's look at a concrete example: we can see mat1 as bins edges of 2D histogram and mat2 as bins heights, so mat1[0] represents bins edges in x-coordinate and mat1[1] representes bins edges in y-coordinate. mat2 represents bins heights on the intersection of x- and y-coordinate edge. So my_matrix_2d stores information about bins edges and heights of bins in 2-dimensional histogram. Its elements are vectors (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat2[i][j]), and because we need one more edge to determine the bins width, the last vectors are (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], None).

Similar in 3D example. mat1[0] (len=m) are bins edges in x-coordinate, mat1[1] (len=n) are bins edges in y-coordinate, mat1[2] (len=o) are bins edges in z-coordinate, and mat2 is mxnxo matrix that contains bins heights. The my_matrix_3d output should be matrix/array with elements (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], mat2[i][j][k]), where i=0,...,m-2, j=0,...,n-2, k=0,...,o-2, and if i=m-1 or j=n-1 or k=o-1, element in matrix should be (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], None).

P.S. my_matrix_nd should be n-dimensional matrix, that has same shape as mat2. But elements in mat2 are floats, but elements in my_matrix_nd are len(mat1)+1 vectors.

EDIT2:

I put the concrete example (2D):

```py
mat1 = [
array([-82.8894492, -56.07043142, -29.25141365, -2.43239587, 24.3866219,  51.20563967,  78.02465745]),
array([-191.15188724, -103.20853717, -15.2651871, 72.67816297, 160.62151304, 248.56486311])
]

mat2 = array([[4.23988548e-08, 3.39190838e-07, 1.27196564e-07, 1.27196564e-07, 0.00000000e+00],
[1.22956679e-06, 8.35257440e-06, 1.53483854e-05, 4.45187976e-06,
1.69595419e-07],
[5.00306487e-06, 4.77835094e-05, 8.47553108e-05, 2.31073759e-05,
1.05997137e-06],
[5.13026143e-06, 5.80016334e-05, 9.37862668e-05, 2.62872900e-05,
1.01757252e-06],
[1.14476908e-06, 1.44156106e-05, 2.33617690e-05, 6.52942364e-06,
2.54393129e-07],
[0.00000000e+00, 5.93583967e-07, 1.10237023e-06, 4.23988548e-07,
4.23988548e-08]])

output:
[

[[-82.88944919513716, -191.1518872423128, 4.2398854812237576e-08], 
[-82.88944919513716, -103.20853717269506, 3.391908384979006e-07], 
[-82.88944919513716, -15.265187103077324, 1.2719656443671272e-07], 
[-82.88944919513716, 72.67816296654041, 1.2719656443671272e-07], 
[-82.88944919513716, 160.62151303615815, 0.0],
[-82.88944919513716, 248.56486310577586, None]],

[[-56.07043142169904, -191.1518872423128, 1.2295667895548898e-06], 
[-56.07043142169904, -103.20853717269506, 8.352574398010803e-06], 
[-56.07043142169904, -15.265187103077324, 1.534838544203e-05], 
[-56.07043142169904, 72.67816296654041, 4.451879755284945e-06], 
[-56.07043142169904, 160.62151303615815, 1.6959541924895036e-07], 
[-56.07043142169904, 248.56486310577586, None]],

[[-29.25141364826092, -191.1518872423128, 5.003064867844034e-06], 
[-29.25141364826092, -103.20853717269506, 4.7783509373391746e-05], 
[-29.25141364826092, -15.265187103077324, 8.475531076966292e-05], 
[-29.25141364826092, 72.67816296654041, 2.3107375872669477e-05], 
[-29.25141364826092, 160.62151303615815, 1.0599713703059398e-06], 
[-29.25141364826092, 248.56486310577586, None]],

[[-2.4323958748228023, -191.1518872423128, 5.130261432280746e-06], 
[-2.4323958748228023, -103.20853717269506, 5.8001633383141e-05], 
[-2.4323958748228023, -15.265187103077324, 9.378626684466952e-05], 
[-2.4323958748228023, 72.67816296654041, 2.628728998358729e-05], 
[-2.4323958748228023, 160.62151303615815, 1.0175725154937022e-06], 
[-2.4323958748228023, 248.56486310577586,None]],

[[24.386621898615317, -191.1518872423128, 1.144769079930414e-06], 
[24.386621898615317, -103.20853717269506, 1.4415610636160767e-05], 
[24.386621898615317, -15.265187103077324, 2.336176900154289e-05], 
[24.386621898615317, 72.67816296654041, 6.529423641084582e-06], 
[24.386621898615317, 160.62151303615815, 2.543931288734254e-07], 
[24.386621898615317, 248.56486310577586, None]],

[[51.20563967205345, -191.1518872423128, 0.0],
[51.20563967205345, -103.20853717269506, 5.935839673713263e-07], 
[51.20563967205345, -15.265187103077324, 1.1023702251181777e-06],
[51.20563967205345, 72.67816296654041, 4.2398854812237604e-07], 
[51.20563967205345, 160.62151303615815, 4.2398854812237616e-08], 
[51.20563967205345, 248.56486310577586, None]],

[[78.02465744549156, -191.1518872423128, None],
[78.02465744549156, -103.20853717269506, None],
[78.02465744549156, -15.265187103077324, None],
[78.02465744549156, 72.67816296654041, None],
[78.02465744549156, 160.62151303615815, None],
[78.02465744549156, 248.56486310577586, None]]

]
```

Comment: This is not understandable, please just provide some input/output concrete examples (mat1, mat2 and result of your function in both 2D and 3D situations).

Comment: Why not use numpy?

Comment: @JohnColeman How?

Comment: Note that `numpy` is rather less efficient for arrays with mixed data types (here, `NoneType` and `float`).  You could use NaN instead if that’s a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion isn’t too complicated:

```
def lookup(m,ii):
  try:
    for i in ii: m=m[i]
  except IndexError: m=None
  return m
def edge_product(mat1,mat2,path=[]):
  return [edge_product(mat1,mat2,path+[i])\
          for i in range(len(mat1[len(path)]))]\
    if len(path)<len(mat1) else\
    [mat1[i] for i in path]+[lookup(mat2,path)]
```

Note that the mutable default argument is not a mistake here: it’s never mutated.